# Plumbing Terminology: Slab leak bypass

Tags: permitting

A slab leak was bypassed by a contractor with a single pipe to the target terminal and does not include changes to the drains or piping to fixtures (toilets, sinks, other user terminals).  What is the correct term for said bypass pipe?  I found the term "[repipe](https://redcapplumbing.com/help-guides/buyers/whats-the-average-cost-of-re-plumbing-a-house-in-florida)", which includes drains.

From a permitting standpoint, is does the bypass fall under the repipe label? or is there another label?

Comment: As with most of these quirky questions, your local authority having jurisdiction ("AHJ") is the final arbiter of whether things need a permit and what they want to name them. (My opinion, though: this is a simple repair.)

Comment: I agree with Aloysius in that there is not a specific name for this. You called it a "slab leak bypass" line and that's as good of a self-explanatory descriptor as anything I can think of.